# Looking for a good translation of "unpublish"

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice

In many content management systems ([CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)) administrators have the option to publish and "unpublish" articles. "Unpublish" disables an public article and sets it private again. What is a good German translation for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use *Veröffentlichung zurückziehen* as tooltip for icons, because the text is lenghty. It translates to *revoke publication*.

A shorter option might be *verstecken*, which is not semantically correct (means *hide*), but is the shortest coresponding word I can think of.

Answer (score 9):

Another word that could be used is *[depublizieren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depublizieren),* but it has a rather specific meaning, which may not be exactly what you are looking for.

German public TV stations are supposed to take down news after a certain time. German public TV is financed by a forced fee from every German household. This rule made because the websites of public German TV stations (and especially their news shows) are not supposed to become a competitor of corporate news websites, which are not publicly financed and would therefore have a disadvantage.

The act of taking down news, especially in accordance to this specific rule, is called *depublizieren.*

Answer (score 6):

There are different options. Assuming you translate "to publish" with "Veröffentlichen", I'd call it "Veröffentlichung aufheben" or "Nicht mehr veröffentlichen". Shorter would be "Verstecken" (= to hide), but that's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: yea, in this case "publish" is translated with "Veröffentlichen"

Comment: Well, the logical counterpart to "veröffentlichen" would be "entöffentlichen", but I don't think that word exists (but then, I'm not sure that "unpublish" is a proper English word either).

Answer (score 3):

You should take into account that in another language it would be better to set up things differently instead of translating.

For example, it would work better in German to have a status indicator Öffentlich/Privat and a button next to it that says "Ändern".